# pygame.event.get() not returning any events when inside a thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I have this code that looks after the user inputs for a pac-man style game.

```
def receiving_inputs(self):
    while True:
        events = pg.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    self.move = 'n'
                elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    self.move = 'e'
                elif event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    self.move = 's'
                elif event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    self.move = 'w'
        time.sleep(1/60)

threading.Thread(target=self.receiving_inputs).start()
```

When I press any keys on my keyboard I do not get any events, however, moving the mouse around will return an event using this code.

The annoying thing is that this exact code works perfectly when not in a thread. i.e when in the program's main loop.

Just fyi I want to use a thread here to minimize the number of times pygame doesn't register a key press (which I'm assuming is due to other things in the mainloop).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get any events at all, because you have to get the events in the main thread.
See the documentation of [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

> [...] The event subsystem should be called from the main thread.

It is only possible to post events from other thread, but the event queue has to be handled in the main thread.

Comment: This does make a lot of sense, but how come I still get mouse events?

Comment: I've no idea what causes that behavior. The documentation just says *'"The event subsystem should be called from the main thread."* - so if you do the event handling in a thread, then the behavior is undefined and probably depends on the system.