# Is there a form to draw the background with concurrent programming in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am developing a videogame in python with pygame and I want to draw the scenary using my function "draw" and concurrent programming to optimize it and use a thread to manage the drawing throughout the run. I used ThreadPoolExecutor to can re-use a thread, but the drawing is very bad because sometimes the backgroung is behind the player(the square) and sometimes it is  in front of the player.

```
import sys
import pygame
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


pygame.init()

# ----------------------------------------
#                 Variables
# ----------------------------------------

width = 600
height = 600

square = pygame.Rect(100,100,100,100)

surface = pygame.display.set_mode( (width, height) )

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

pygame.display.set_caption('Texto')

font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 24)


# ----------------------------------------
#                 Function
# ----------------------------------------


def draw():

    surface.fill((20, 210, 190))


# ----------------------------------------
#                   Loop
# ----------------------------------------


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    executor.submit(draw)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface,(100,100,100),square)

    pygame.display.update()
```

How can I do to have the background behind the player and do it re-using a thread to optimize it?

Comment: But why do you want to use a thread? You can just render the background then the player itself in the mainloop.

Comment: I'm still learning, but I thought that if I can do that with a thread I will be able to optimize it when my game is more extensive and free up graphic resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do all the drawing in a single thread. There is not any benefit of drawing the background in a different thread. They cannot guarantee the order of execution between different threads.

```py
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    surface.fill((20, 210, 190))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface,(100,100,100),square)
    pygame.display.update()
```

It is common for all graphics pipe operations to be performed on a single thread. Whereas the game logic can be done in a different thread.
With pygame, you also need to handle the events on the main thread (see  [pygame.event.get() not returning any events when inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717184/pygame-event-get-not-returning-any-events-when-inside-a-thread/56717299#56717299)).