# Running infinite loops using threads in Pygame

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I encountered a problem. If you have a solution for it, please tell me how you are doing.

I have several functions that I have to use multithreading, each of which has a While loop inside. And when I use multithreading, pygame runs into problems. I also prepared a sample code to make the problem easier to understand.
Please guide me in understanding this problem.

Why does pygame freeze and the program does not run properly?

```
import threading
import pygame

pygame.init()
SIZE = DW, DH = 900, 600
DS = pygame.display.set_mode(size=SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Stackoverflow/Pygame/Multithreading")
FPS = 60


def main():
    x = DW // 2
    y = DH // 2
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.display.update()
        DS.fill(0)
        clock.tick(60)
        
        
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += 5
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += 5
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= 5
        
        
        pygame.draw.circle(surface=DS, color=(255, 100, 100), center=(x, y), radius=15)


def one():
    while True:
        print("One")


def two():
    while True:
        print("Two")


t1 = threading.Thread(target=main)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=one) 
t3 = threading.Thread(target=two)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
```

Comment: Don't use inifinite while loops, especially ones with single print in them as it will absolutely murder your resources.

Comment: This is a sample code just to understand the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Typically you will want to do one iteration of `one` and/or one iteration of `two` in the main pygame loop. Otherwise, you will need to pass to the threads a function that they should call whenever they have a usable result to share with the main loop.

Comment: The events need to be handled in the main thread. See [pygame.event.get() not returning any events when inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717184/pygame-event-get-not-returning-any-events-when-inside-a-thread/56717299#56717299)

Comment: @PabloGutierrezMarques Basically I want to bring 2 AIs into Pong so that each AI can control a paddle and play together.

Comment: @Rabbid76  So do you think if we want to modify this code we have to bring out while inside main? It's a little difficult for me to understand the subject, please help me more

Comment: @AmirKhazaee I don't know if that's the only problem, but you can't call `pygame.event.get()` from within a thread.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm very happy that there are codes and examples for you to learn pygame. I personally read most of your code. Thank you if you modify the sample code I wrote to understand this. Because I know a lot of novice programmers may be asking questions like myself.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve the problem and I will post the solution for you.

```
import threading
import pygame

pygame.init()
SIZE = DW, DH = 900, 600
DS = pygame.display.set_mode(size=SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Stackoverflow/Pygame/Multithreading")


def main():
    x = DW // 2
    y = DH // 2
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.display.update()
        DS.fill(0)
        clock.tick(60)
        
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += 5
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += 5
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= 5
        
        
        pygame.draw.circle(surface=DS, color=(255, 100, 100), center=(x, y), radius=15)


def one():
    while True:
        if not pygame.get_init():
            break
        pass


def two():
    while True:
        if not pygame.get_init():
            break
        pass

t2 = threading.Thread(target=one) 
t3 = threading.Thread(target=two)


t2.start()
t3.start()

main()
```